Wavelength of Gravitational Wave and Armlength of Detector
My book on gravitational waves states that, in an interferometer like LIGO, the armlength
of either arm shouldn't be bigger than the wavelength of a gravitational wave in order for the
detector to pick up the signal.
I'm not sure on why the detector wouldn't be able to pick up the signal if the armlength would be bigger than $\lambda_{\mathrm{gw}}$. Could anyone provide an intuitive explanation?

Related & possibly containing at least a partial answer: Difference between gravitational wave detectors
